# Adding items dynamically to Windows Explorer's context menu

Tags: java, windows, registry, contextmenu

I want to do the following:

When a user right clicks on any file (in windows) I want the context menu to popup a special item. I did that with regedit and I followed a few examples on the internet and got this

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Do something]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Do something\command]
@="notepad.exe %1"
```

That works OK, but I would like to run a java application and send it the selected item's file-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider running a batch script file instead of placing the entire java command in regedit. This may be easier to debug, as you can run the batch file manually and ensure it works. Just replace "notepad.exe" with your batch file.

You will need to pass the parameters passed to the batch file along to your java application. Here's a quick reference to parameters in batch files: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php

Comment: ok that sounds great. Im no windows expert so this is what I did:
I created a .bat file with only one line
java C:/.../myjavaApp.jar param1 
But i have 2 problems, the first one is the .bat window doesn't close automatically, the second is that I dont know how to pass param1 as the selected file path